# MS Access Database Yes/No not updating properly

Tags: c#, .net, database

for the function, which is why I am doing it with OleDbParamteres instead of OleDbCommands. I have been searching through various posts on stackoverflow and none of the solutions seem to match what I am trying to do exactly. My teacher requires a certain format (stupid I know) and here is what I have.

```
public void UpdateUserLocked(string Path, string userID, bool lockAcc)
{
    // Declare and Instantiate the OleDb connection using the access connection string and database path
    OleDbConnection sqlConn = new OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Path + "");
    sqlConn.Open();

    // Declare and instantiate a new OleDbCommand
    OleDbCommand oCommand = new OleDbCommand();
    oCommand.Connection = sqlConn;
    string stmt = "UPDATE tblUsers SET Locked = @lockAcc WHERE (tblUsers.UserID = @id)";

    //Declare new OleDbParameter for later use
    OleDbParameter param;

    // Instantiate a new parameter to be used later
    param = new OleDbParameter();

    //Create user id paramater
    param = new OleDbParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@id";
    param.Value = userID;
    oCommand.Parameters.Add(param);

    //Create locked parameter
    param = new OleDbParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@lockAcc";
    param.Value = lockAcc;
    oCommand.Parameters.Add(param);

    // Exectute the sql statement
    oCommand.CommandText = stmt;
    oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // Close the sql connection
    sqlConn.Close();
}
```

The function is called when someone fails login 3 times, and executes fine. However, the database is not actually being updated. The database has an ID, UserID, UserPassword, and Locked column. No 2 usernames, or passwords are the same, in this case, so I do not need to use the userID and password in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `OleDbCommand` instead of `SqlCommand`, you cannot use named parameters.

For example, change your query text to:

```
string stmt = "UPDATE dbo.tblUsers SET Locked = ? WHERE (dbo.tblUsers.UserID = ?)";
```

Now your parameters have to follow in order of the question marks:

```
//Create locked parameter
param = new OleDbParameter();
param.Value = lockAcc;
oCommand.Parameters.Add(param);

//Create user id paramater
param = new OleDbParameter();
param.Value = userID;
oCommand.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Alternatively you can swap to using `SqlConnnection` instead of `OleDbConnection`, and continue as you originally planned (using named parameters).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx), the `OleDbCommand` does not support named parameters:

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
>   parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an
>   OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the
>   question mark (?) placeholder must be used.

So change your query text to:

```
string stmt = "UPDATE tblUsers SET Locked = ? WHERE tblUsers.UserID = ?";
```

You will also have to switch the order you are adding the parameters to the command.  Because the parameters are not named, they are processed in the order they are listed in the SQL statement.  So the parameter for `Locked` must be first, following by the `UserID`.